# Safari nested z-index problems

Tags: html, css, safari, z-index

I am having some trouble with safari and displaying a popup over a navigation element. For some reason the given z-index is ignored and the popup is hidden behind the navigation.

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<section class="application">
<header class="application-header"></header>
<nav class="application-navigation"></nav>
<div class="application-content">
  <div class="wizard-background">
    <div class="wizard-content">TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here the less code

```
.application {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    &-navigation {
        position: absolute;
        background: green;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 50px;
    }

    &-header {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 50px;
    }

    &-content {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 81;
        left: 200px;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: yellow;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
.wizard {

     &-background {
         z-index: 100;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         position: fixed;
         background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      &-content {
          position: fixed;
          top: 100px;
          left: 150px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background: white;
          z-index: 101;
      }
}
```

When you view this code in safari you can see that the "wizard-content" is partly hidden behind the "navigation-content". If you remove the z-index from "application-content" it works fine.

I also prepared a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Thorvid/pen/jJareN) where you can see result, but you have to use safari to see the effect I mean.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Or how safari works different than all other browsers regarding z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Safari messes up the z-index like that, but if you add `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to a parent element it usually starts acting normal.

here is a fork to your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Barabrian/pen/oNgLKPZ).

In this case I added it to .application

```css
.application {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```